# The symmetric Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $A\triangle B := A\cup B-A\cap B $ a suitable definition for the symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B?$
Or is $A\triangle B := (A-B) \cup (B-A) $ only allowed?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "only allowed"?

Comment: Is one definition the “correct” one.

Comment: Correct in what sense? Are you asking if one is the "official definition", whatever that means? (It doesn't mean anything, there is no entity issuing "official" notions.) Or are you asking if one of the two versions you presented is erroneous?

Comment: Official definition I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two definitions lead to the same set. Hence define the symmetric difference as you prefer.

Comment: Of course, it takes a (very simple) *proof* to show this equivalence. So strictly speaking, you start by defining the symmetric difference using one definition and then prove that the alternate characterization works.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I felt like typing it out, here it is explicitly.

Use distributive property of set unions and intersections, and note that $A-B=A\cap B^c$: 
$$\begin{aligned}
(A-B)\cup (B-A)&=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B)\\
&=(A\cup (A^c \cap B))\cap (B^c\cup (A^c \cap B))\\
&=((A\cup A^c) \cap (A\cup B))\cap ((A^c\cup B^c) \cap (B\cup B^c))\\
&=(S \cap (A\cup B))\cap ((A^c\cup B^c) \cap S)\\
&=(A\cup B)\cap (A^c\cup B^c)\\
&=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c\\
&=(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)
\end{aligned}$$